# aplicate a conditional funcion to a column looking for a common text of the values

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a data frame called `INFO_X_RADIO_SUCURSAL`, and I need to create a new vector (column) called `ZONA`. The values of `ZONA` need to be "MONTEVIDEO" if in the column called `LOCALIDAD` appears the word "Montevdeo", but the problem is that in `LOCALIDAD` I have lots of values which contains the word montevideo, so, I need to use a condition which involve all this cases, something like: if in `LOCALIDAD` you read "Mont.." put here in `ZONA` "MONTEVIDEO"

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: INFO_X_RADIO_SUCURSAL$ZONA[INFO_X_RADIO_SUCURSAL$LOCALIDAD == "MONTEVIDEO" ] <- "MONTEVIDEO"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grepl` is the function you want: it searches through text for the given string rather than testing equality:

```
INFO_X_RADIO_SUCURSAL$ZONA <- grepl(
  "Montevdeo", ## pattern you are looking for
  INFO_X_RADIO_SUCURSAL$LOCALIDAD, ## where to look for it
  ignore.case=TRUE, ## you don't care if it's caps or not
  fixed=TRUE ## the pattern is a simple one (not a regular expression)
)
```

This has TRUE where "Montevideo" is in the given column and FALSE otherwise. You wanted to have "Montevideo" and "" instead of these logical values, so run

```
INFO_X_RADIO_SUCURSAL$ZONA <- ifelse(INFO_X_RADIO_SUCURSAL$ZONA,"MONTEVIDEO","")
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, its ok. And i add a last point of complex , now to finish the work i need to aplicate the command in two columns: look for "montevideo" in LOCALIDAD, and look for "Casa Central" in SUCURSAL.